# Получить сумму процентов от числа

Tags: математика

Подскажите, как мне получить сумму процентов, которую вычли из определенной стоимости, если мне известна конечная стоимость и сумма %, которую вычитали
т.е. 
Я имею 15500 - это конечная сумма, из неё поочередно вычитали 20%, 30% и 5%, мне известно только 55% и 15500.

Хочу получить реальную сумму, вычитаемых процентов от ПЕРВОНАЧАЛЬНОЙ стоимости

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он не имеет отношения к тематике сайта.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если из суммы поочередно вычитать 20, 30 и 5 процентов, получится так:

```
x
```

После вычитания 20%

```
x - 0.2*x = 0.8*x
```

После вычитания 30%

```
0.8*x - 0.8* x * 0.3 = 0.56*x
```

После вычитания 5%

```
0.56*x - 0.56*x*0.05 = 0.532*x
```

Т.е. реально вычтено 46.8%

Если известно только 55%... ваши 55 % могут быть просто разовыми 55% - и тогда вы их и получите.

Или 11 раз по 5% - т.е. примерно 43.1% вычтенных.

Так что задача неоднозначна - если я правильно ее понял. Если нет - поясните, пожалуйста, понятнее, что дано и что надо получить.

Comment: например есть некая сумма, мы знаем, что вычли из неё 20% и 5%  - итоговый % скидки относительно первоначальной стоимости получается 24%
вот нужно найти этот % от первоначальной стоимости зная только сколько % вычитали и итоговую сумму

Comment: То есть 20% и 5% известны? Тогда все просто - перемножить все `(1-p_i)`, и вычесть из 1. В вашем случае 20 и 5% - `1 - (1-0.2)(1-0.05) = 0.24`. Если после этого получилась сумма S, то изначально была `S/(1-p)`, где `p` - итоговый процент. Например, если вышло 760 - то было `760/(1-0.24) = 1000`: после 20% осталось 800, после 5% осталось 760...